# .Net: How to get the modified proxy at runtime

Tags: .net

When my application is running, the system (IE) proxy is modified, how can I get the latest system (IE) proxy without restarting the application.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more of your current requirement ? because based on your type of your application (web/windows) or Application architecture the full fledged solution can differ. ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.